# Telegram Bot update_id in getupdate methods sometimes jumps

Tags: telegram-bot

I have joined a bot in a group to archive the messages. I'm coding a php code for archiving, till this get complete, I manually getupdates from the browser. and save the results in a text file. and frequently I use offset to get newer msgs. but next time when I getupdates after offset (for example one after that) I see that I have a jump! for example if the last id was 1500, after getupdate I see 1553 or 1540, and I donn't see the msgs in the gap. anyone can help me,please?

Answer (score 0):

I may be because old updates are deleted if not requested in a period of time (about 24 hours).

From https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates:

> Incoming updates are stored on the server until the bot receives them [...], but they will not be kept longer than 24 hours.

What I am not sure is if the lost updates consume `update_id` values.